# A variant of the divisor function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Let $m_1, m_2$ be positive integers (not necessarily co-prime) and let $S_1, S_2$ be a set of congruence classes modulo $m_1, m_2$ respectively. Let $P_1, P_2$ be the set of prime numbers belonging to some congruence class in $S_1, S_2$ respectively. Define a multiplicative function $\rho = \rho_{S_1, S_2}$ on prime powers by:

$$\displaystyle \rho(p^k) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } p \not\in P_1, P_2 \\
1 & \text{if } p \in P_1, p \not\in P_2 \\
1 & \text{if } p \in P_2, p \not\in P_1 \\ 
k+1 & \text{if } p \in P_1 \cap P_2.\end{cases}$$

In particular, if $P_1 = P_2 = P$, the set of all primes, then $\rho$ is just the usual divisor function.

How does one evaluate the sum

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n \leq X} \rho(n)^2$$

asymptotically?

Comment: The Dirichlet series is $F(s)=\exp(\sum_{\chi \bmod q} c_\chi  \log L(s,\chi))= \zeta(s)^{c_{\chi_0}} \exp(...)$ where $S_1,S_2$ both are a sets of congruence classes modulo $q$ and $c_{\chi_0} > 0$ so you are asking about applying the Tauberian theorems to such thing, the asymptotic works as usual but the error term will be only $1/\log X$ smaller.

Comment: You could try to use the Selberg–Delange method (for example Chapter II.5 of Tenenbaum's book).